# Webservice API for my Java App Engine GWT app

Tags: java, web-services, google-app-engine

I'm creating a web app that runs on Google App Engine. I'm also developing a desktop client that needs to access/update data on the webapp.

I would like to create a web sevice api between the server and the client. What would be my best options?

According to GAE the do not support RMI og JAX out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to answer my own question but Restlet is working on a GAE version. The current development version seems to work well.

http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_1.2/13-restlet/252-restlet.html